# DrawerLayout inside fragment.xml not showing on home icon click

Tags: android, drawerlayout

**Background**

I'm trying to implement a Drawer Navigation inside my fragment. I would prefer to have it there rather than in my main activity because I'm trying to handle toolbars per fragment and having the Drawerlayout coupled would make it easier to setup.

**Problem**

When I click on the hamburger home button, no drawer layout is displayed. How do I resolve this issue while keeping the drawerlayout inside my fragment.xml file instead of moving it to activity?

**Things I've Tried**

- Followed the [Android Navigation Drawer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer)
- Made sure my xml layout hierarchy matches the requirements

*fragment.xml*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_article_topics"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/articles_swipe_to_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/articles"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_article_topic" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*activity.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

*Fragment.java*

```
@BindView(R.id.drawer_article_topics)
DrawerLayout articleTopicDrawerLayout;

// Other code

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_articles_refresh:
            articleListingViewModel.startRefresh();
            refresh();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            articleTopicDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setDrawerIcon();
    setupRecyclerView();
    setupSwipeRefreshLayout();
}

private void setDrawerIcon() {
    if (isAdded()) {
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to lie with DrawerLayout.openDrawer() and the Android Material Components library. Because I was inheriting Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar in my AppTheme, the Navigation Drawer did not open. Until they add a fix in, the workaround is to add this to your App Theme:

`<item name="navigationViewStyle">@style/Widget.Design.NavigationView</item>`

More information here:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/133